# Strange inheritance in CSS

Tags: html, css, inheritance

I have a following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    table {
        border: solid red 2px;
    }
    tr {
        border: solid red 2px;
    }
    td {
        border: inherit;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td> 1 </td> <td> 2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> 1 </td> <td> 2 </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

It works correctly. A property border of "tr" inherit by child "td".

But this code work differently, in spite of fact, that logical of work is the same:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    table {
        border: solid red 2px;
    }
    tr {
        border: inherit;
    }
    td {
        border: inherit;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td> 1 </td> <td> 2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> 1 </td> <td> 2 </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

There is property border of "tr" don't inherit by child "td". Why?

Comment: `tr` is `td`'s child?

Comment: Vise versa. If I write a question incorrectly edit him please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the final html that is rendered, tr is not child of table but tbody.

Hierarchy is: `table` -> **`tbody`** -> `tr`

Default border of tbody is not inherit but `medium , therefore, tr doesn't inherit.

Try this:

```
tbody, tr {
    border: inherit;
}
```

Comment: It is nice explanation. I don't know about a existing of a implicit tag `tbody`... damn.

Comment: it's still valid not to explicitly put tbody. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tbody.html **A tbody element's start tag may be omitted if the first thing inside the tbody element is a tr element**